# Avoid triggering build on certain file changes (e.g README.md)

Tags: jenkins, github, github-webhook

Is there any way to avoid triggering build on certain file commits which are not directly related to source code?

e.g. I don't want to trigger a automatic build when anyone make changes to README.md file or some reference document file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that it's described in the [plugin page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git) or the [Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-AdvancedFeatures), but at least according to the Advanced Features/Additional Behaviors, the git plugin can be configured to do what you're looking for in multiple ways. 
eg: `Polling ignores commits in certain paths` lets you specify  an **Included region** or **Excluded region**" The help (?) says:

> Each exclusion uses java regular expression pattern matching, and must
>   be separated by a new line.
>
> ```
> myapp/src/main/web/.*\.html
> myapp/src/main/web/.*\.jpeg
> myapp/src/main/web/.*\.gif
> ```
>
> The example above illustrates that if only html/jpeg/gif files have been committed to the SCM a build will not occur.

You'd have to try them out. One less plugin - KISS!

[image: Git Advanced Features]

Comment: does it allow direct file path or wildcard? did you try?

Comment: Added details. Didi not try but help says Java regex supported.

Comment: Also supports the feature in your response - skip a build on any file commit which has this keyword [ci skip].

Answer (score 0):

After searching for quite a while I finally found a [Jenkins plugin](https://github.com/banyan/jenkins-ci-skip-plugin) which can skip the build when there is keyword "[ci skip]" in the commit message.

**This allows to skip a build on any file commit which has this keyword [ci skip].**

only disadvantage is, it will skip the build even if somebody puts [ci skip] in a code file commit

Github: [jenkins-ci-skip-plugin](https://github.com/banyan/jenkins-ci-skip-plugin)